# Elasticsearch : search word with regexp

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm newbie in Elasticsearch and I want to search with regexp.
I have an index with object that contain field named equipments that will be like that :

case 1 : `equipments=Name:foo bar|price:1000|Name:bar foo|price:1200`

case 2 : `equipments=Name:foo bar|price:1000|Name:foo bar|price:1200`

Imagine that I do this query :

```
{
"regexp": {
  "equipment.keyword": {
    "value": ".*Name:.*oo ba.*"
  }
}
}
```

That return only the first case and not the second. I tried to use the field and not it keyword but it's analyzed and not accept withespaces.

Can you help me please to find a way ?

**EDIT** : Mapping of our field

```
{
"rec_index-1": {
    "mappings": {
        "biens": {
            "full_name": "equipments",
            "mapping": {
                "equipments": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It's a typical case where you should preprocess the value of the `equipments` field (e.g. using the [`kv` ingest processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/kv-processor.html)) and split it into more queryable values.

Comment: I know that my field not saved in the best way but we cannot update it as it used by other applications. There is no solution to search without making any changes ?

Comment: You can always reprocess that field and store the parsed result into other fields, so that you can use them efficiently and you don't impact other applications using the raw data. Easily done with update by query and an ingest pipeline

Comment: It's also in the best interest of the other applications in need of this index, because  regexp queries are strongly discouraged (especially the ones with prefix wildcards) and will put a heavy burden on your cluster.

Comment: I understand that and I will work on it. But I prefer have an idea if there is a solution to get boths records with our use case if you have it.
Thanks

Comment: What's the current mapping of that `equipments` field?

Comment: @Val, I added the mapping in the description.

Comment: Thanks, why do you have `.*` and `*.` in your regexp?

Comment: Mistake of copy/past ! sorry